# Fastify-http-proxy unable to get dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, fastify

I have a fastify server that's pointing to two "backend" fastify servers and I'd like to generate a random number that is then used to decide which backend to route to.

Currently it only works the first time, and I'm unable to override the upstream afterwards.

```
server.register(require('fastify-http-proxy'), {
  upstream: '',
  replyOptions: { 
    getUpstream: (originalReq, base) => {
      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        console.log(`setting base to backend1`)
        return `http://localhost:${backend1Port}`
      } else {
        console.log(`setting base to backend2`)
        return `http://localhost:${backend2Port}`
      }
    },
    disableCache: true,
    cacheURLs: 0,
  },
})
```

How can I make it so that upon refresh it might change where it routes to?

Comment: Do you see the console.log() statements every time you refresh? Are you saying it's hitting the "other" conditional branch but not update the path?

Comment: Yes I see it every time I refresh. It looks like this:
setting base to backend2
hitting backend2 
setting base to backend1
hitting backend2

Comment: And then you no longer see any console.log statements when it's running?

Comment: Sorry, I should specify that I'm going to localhost:3000 and refreshing there (not rerunning node server.js), so I see the console.log statements every time I refresh the web page while running node. I get the same effect when doing curl

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. disableCache needed to be outside of replyOptions.

```
server.register(require('fastify-http-proxy'), {
  upstream: '',
  replyOptions: { 
    getUpstream: (originalReq, base) => {
      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        console.log(`setting base to backend1`)
        return `http://localhost:${backend1Port}`
      } else {
        console.log(`setting base to backend2`)
        return `http://localhost:${backend2Port}`
      }
    },
    disableCache: true,
    cacheURLs: 0,
  },
})
```